# iOS OpenGL glClear crash when starting app

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

In our game we use OpenGL for rendering.
Sometimes app randomly crashes just after starting when calling this method first time:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

We are making call of this method before rendering the game scene.
Here's the stack trace of crash:

```
0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000a4

0 IMGSGX543GLDriver sgxTextureGetImageRowBytes(GLDTextureRec*, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 7
1 IMGSGX543GLDriver CalculateChunkPlaneSizes(GLDTextureRec*, int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*) + 108
2 IMGSGX543GLDriver CalculateChunkPlaneSizes(GLDTextureRec*, int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*) + 108
3 IMGSGX543GLDriver sgxConfigureTexturePrivate(GLDTextureRec*) + 82
4 IMGSGX543GLDriver glrUpdateTexture + 952
5 libGPUSupportMercury.dylib gldLoadFramebuffer + 110
6 GLEngine gleUpdateDrawFramebufferState
7 GLEngine glClear_Exec + 164
```

We don't have any idea why this crash may appear.
Does anybody encounter similar issue?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you try  posting on the powervr and apple developer forum?  i had some problems myself with ios giving me a context that was "not ready yet" that i never resolved...   i had to move some logic from executing on the first frame only  to executing every frame.

Comment: @racarate, Thanks for an advice, I'll ask this question there. By the way, I do call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` on every frame. Maybe I should skip first frame and try to call rendering methods on next frame? What do you think?

Comment: Hey Sergei, did you fixed this somehow? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @SuleaCosmin, not yet, still can't understand the reason of this issue.

Comment: @Sergei ... it looks device specific